# Kotlin native interface

Tags: java-native-interface, kotlin

Does Kotlin use the same native interface implementation as Java under the hood?
Is it as efficient (or ineffecient) as in Java (cost of objects transfer, byte streams, etc.)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the hood, the implementation is the same, because it will be converted to the same Java code. It means that it's efficient as your Java code.

Given this Kotlin class with the native method `nativeMethod()`:

```
class ExampleJni {

    companion object {
        init {
            System.loadLibrary("example-jni")
        }
    }

    external fun nativeMethod(): String
}
```

It will use the "same" implementation of this Java class (the conversion isn't exactly the same, but it won't impact the native implementation):

```
public class ExampleJni {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("hello-jni");
    }

    public final native String nativeMethod();
}
```

**EDIT**

To be more clear about the conversion. If you decompile the Kotlin code, you can see that it's converted to two classes.
The first one is containing the native methods:

```
@dalvik.annotation.MemberClasses 
@kotlin.Metadata 
public final class ExampleJni {

    public static final ExampleJni$Companion Companion;

    public ExampleJni() { ... }

    static void <clinit>() { ... }
    @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull 
    // Here you can see that the implementation is the same.
    public final native String nativeMethod() { ... }
}
```

The other one is the inner class related to the `companion object`.

```
@dalvik.annotation.EnclosingClass 
@dalvik.annotation.InnerClass 
@kotlin.Metadata 
public final class ExampleJni$Companion {

    private ExampleJni$Companion() { ... }
    public ExampleJni$Companion(DefaultConstructorMarker) { ... }
}
```